# How to migrate an SQLServer 2000 database from one machine to another

Tags: sql-server

This January I'm migrating our main SQL Server 2000 based database to a beefier server.

Is there any standard procedure or documentation on how to do it? I need to replicate all at the new server (databases, jobs, DTSs, vinculated servers, etc).

Comment: What is a "vinculated server"?

Comment: Sorry if in the English version is called in another way, maybe is called Linked servers or something like that. Those are other databases, wich can be from other vendors, that you can query from withing SQLServer if it's configured as needed.

Comment: The english name is "linked servers".

Answer (score 1):

There are things that you can migrate quite easily (databases) and things that require a lot more works (security, jobs). There is no "standard" procedure for migrating *everything* in a single step: each thing needs to be migrated differently.

My suggestion is to look for a qualified DBA, who will be able to properly understand what needs to be done and then do it.

Comment: In fairness, @joeqwerty, he said "year-based versions".

Comment: +1 for the phrase "qualified DBA".